# Awaiting ME decision and reviewers selection

Tags: publications, editors

I submitted a manuscript through ScholarOne two months ago. During the first week they asked me a few doubts and once they were answered, the manuscript status appeared as "awaiting reviewer selection". Then they change the status to "awaiting ME decision" and stayed this way until a week ago, when they changed iy back to "awaiting reviewer selection"
I'm a bit confused. Can anyone give me an explanation? Thanks